# Uniqueness of ruling for a ruled surface

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Suppose one has two isomorphic (geometrically) ruled surface $C_1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $C_2\times \mathbb{P}^1$, how can we show $C_1$ is isomorphic to $C_2$?

Thanks!

Comment: I will assume that $C_1,C_2$ are smooth projective for simplicity. Then $g(C_1)=g(C_2)$ since both are $h^1(C_1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. If it is zero, $C_1=C_2=\mathbb{P}^1$. So, assume $g>0$. Then, consider the composition, $C_1\times \{p\}\subset C_1\times\mathbb{P}^1=C_2\times \mathbb{P}^1\to C_2$. Show that this is non-constant and thus an isomorphism. ($g=1$, requires an extra argument).

Comment: @Mohan I suppose the final step is using Hurwitz's Theorem?

Comment: Yes, any non-constant map between two genus $g>1$ curves must be an isomorphism by Hurwitz.

Comment: You can also show this via field theory: see [Ohm](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=JTNB_1989__1_1_27_0), who follows [Nagata](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118802001), or [Deveney](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2043383). I was going to say that this has the advantage for showing the claim for *birationally* ruled surfaces as well, but it looks like the argument by @Mohan works for that case, too.