# Hartshorne V Exercise 2.1: How to show such curve is unique?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise I was solving is stated below:

> $2.1.$ If $X$ is a birationally ruled surface, show that the curve $C$, such that $X$ is birationally equivalent to $C \times \Bbb{P}^{1}$, is unique (up to isomorphism).

I just want to show that: if we have two projective smooth curves $C$ and $C'$ such that $C\times \Bbb P^1$ is birationally equivalent to $C'\times \Bbb P^1$, then we can find two open sets $U$ and $U'$ in $C$ and $C'$ respectively, such that $U\simeq U'$.

But I wasn't able to proceed in solving the problem. Could you provide some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions to similar problems on here somewhat unsatisfactory, so I'll add a different one here. (See the [comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715815/uniqueness-of-ruling-for-a-ruled-surface) as well as the related questions.)
$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$

Let $\psi:\P^1 \times C \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1 \times C'$ be the birational map in question. Let $s, s'$ be respective sections that intersect the regular locus of $\psi$ and $\psi^{-1}$, so that they give rational maps $C \dashrightarrow \P^1 \times C$ and $C' \dashrightarrow \P^1 \times C'$ which are local sections of the projection maps $\pi$, $\pi'$, to $C$ and $C'$ respectively. If both $C$ and $C'$ have genus $0$, we would be done so assume $C$ has genus $g >0 $.

We can first observe that in any case, we can compose these to obtain rational maps $C \dashrightarrow C'$ and $C' \dashrightarrow C$. Since $C, C'$ are smooth projective curves, it follows that these maps are regular. Furthermore, since the genus of $C$ is nonzero, an open subset of it cannot map injectively into a fibre, so this map is also nonconstant and finite. By Hurwitz' theorem, it follow that $C$ and $C'$ have the same genus. (cf. example IV.2.5.4 in Hartshorne)

Since all smooth projective curves of genus $0$ are isomorphic to $\P^1$, we may assume $C$ and $C'$ have genus $g > 0$. Now, composing the inclusion of any fibre of $\pi$, intersecting the regular locus, with $\psi$ and $\pi'$ yields a rational map, and hence a morphism $\P^1 \to C'$ which is regular. Since $g >0$, only way this can happen is if this map is constant. Hence, $\psi$ and $\psi^{-1}$ send fibres into fibres where they're defined.

Lastly, we will show the separable part of $C \to C'$ has degree 1, by showing that a general point of $C'$ has exactly one preimage. Indeed, pick $Q \in C'$ so that the preimages land in the open set we used to define this morphism. Then, if $P, P' \mapsto Q$, then $\psi(s(P))), \psi(s(P'))$ are in the fibre over $Q$. Hence, $s(P)$ and $s(P')$ are in the same fibre over $C$, which implies that $P = P'$.

**Remark:** If $C, C'$ have genus $g \geq 2$, then any map $C \to C'$ must be an isomorphism by Hurwitz' theorem. On the other hand for $g = 0$ any such curves will be isomorphic to $\P^1$, so there's nothing to prove. This reduces us to the case that these are elliptic curves, which is one of the suggested solutions in the linked comments.